# Are there any asp.net or jquery wysiwyg editors that work inside an updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, editor, updatepanel

I've tried multiple editors and have been able to successfully find one that works 100% of the time in an updatepanel and in IE8. ckeditor works fine until a postback in which it fires a hidden error. There are posts on it but no successful resolutions. I was wondering if anyone has an example site that successfully used an editor in an updatepanel that works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give http://freetextbox.com/ a try.

**Edit**: I see you wanted a sample site; I don't think they have an example, but I've used it in countless UpdatePanels and it works in all major browsers no issue.

Comment: Tried it, it conflicts with jquery and causes any jquery to fail because it uses prototype framework.

Comment: @Troy - you can get jquery and prototype to work side-by-side:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $j = jQuery;
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You could giva a try to this:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx

Comment: Couldn't get to this work in an modal popup inside an updatepanel.