# Need good HTML content editor for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

I need a Javascipt text editor which can be used to write posts by portal users. It should provide at least some text formatting and image stored on other sites insertion. Moreover, really important things is a solution to filter text on server side to get rid of security issues. I'm using the ASP.NET platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is lots of options if you are not needing to use the control in an update panel:

1. [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/) (Seems to be the most ASP.NET friendly, haven't used)
2. [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
3. [AJAX Toolkit HTML Editor](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/htmleditor/htmleditor.aspx)
4. [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

The situation where you run into problems when using these with ASP.NET is when they are wrapped within update panels. There are many annoyances setting the hooks in place to trigger the controls to update upon the async postback and refresh themselves when the request ends. I have spent many hours attempting to get these to work with update panels with much frustration.

[Related Question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906265/are-there-any-asp-net-or-jquery-wysiwyg-editors-that-work-inside-an-updatepanel)

Answer (score 1):

If you like the editor on SO, you could use it:  [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) and [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Answer (score 0):

Try TinyMCE http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's a crossover here with this question (assuming you want to use jQuery of course):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141073/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-for-use-with-jquery